# get position of an element and display a div after it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 10 different buttons and i want to show a hidden div exactly down from the button the user pressed.the div is currenlty showing exactly at the block the code of div is istead of taking new cords top: left:

THE function call:

```
<img style="position:relative;float:right;padding-top:7px;" onclick="find_pos(this)" src="images/view_comments.png"></li></a>



function find_pos(ele) {

    var x=0;
    var y=0;
    while(true){
        x += ele.offsetLeft;
        y += ele.offsetTop;
        if(ele.offsetParent === null){
            break;
        }
        ele = ele.offsetParent;
    }
hidden_comment_form.style.display='block';
hidden_comment_form.style.top=y;
hidden_comment_form.style.left=x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you 2 options :
option 1 :

```
<div class="main">
<button class="btn">a</button>
<div class="toggle"> a toggle this </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <button class="btn">b</button>
  <div class="toggle"> b toggle this </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button.btn').on('click', function() {
      var $div =  $(this).siblings('.toggle');
      $div.toggle();
   })
 })
</script>
```

option 2:

```
<button class="btn">a</button>
<div class="toggle"> a toggle this </div>

<button class="btn">b</button>
<div class="toggle"> b toggle this </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button.btn').on('click', function() {
      var $div =  $(this).next();
      $div.toggle();
  })
})
</script>
```

i suggest option 1 is better

Comment: but this mean i have to c/p the code i want to show exactly after the button.Is There any way to just grab the coordinates of button and display with with position absolute after the button ?

Comment: the 1st option can access any `div`, just put it in the same level of `button` and `siblings` works well. Or what you want is can hide/show `div` in random place with no rule?

Comment: wanted to hide/show a huge div that contains a form , exactly after the button. with your way i think i have to c/p that huge div 10 times and make it invisible. right ?

Comment: it's depend on you. Bind which class you want to toggle, then use `siblings(classToggle)`, it toggles all the `<element/>` has class `classToggle` putting in the sample level with the `button`